# Update TableA values based on Values from TableB (multiple options)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Two tables:

```
           TableA
+************************************+
|Col1   | code    | Country | Value2 |
+************************************+
|Field1 | IN      | INDIA   | NA     |
|Field2 | CA      | CANADA  | NA     |
|Field3 | US      | USA     | NA     |
+************************************+

        TableB
+***************************+
|Field1  | Field2  | Field3 |
+***************************+
|1       | 4       |   IN   |
|2       | 5       |   CA   |
|3       | 6       |   -    |
+***************************+
```

I am trying to update column `Field3` in `TableB`, Based on values from Column `Country` in `TableA`

That is: If `Field3` in `TableB` has Value `IN` then it should get updated to `India`

or If `Filed3` has Value `CA` it should get updated to `Canada`

and in the third case if no matching value is present then it should get update to "NA" or "NotSpecified"

So far I have tried updating `TableB` using a `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE TableB SET TableB.Field3 = TableA.Country
FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.Field3 = TableA.Code
```

I am really struggling update table based on multiple `IF` statements? Should I use `CASE`?

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: "*if no matching value is present then it should get update to whatever is the value in column Value2 in TableA*", if there is no matching value, how do you plan on arriving Value2 from TableA?

Comment: @EzLo what I mean here is, if Field3 has no matching value in Code from TableA, then it should get substituted to "NA" or "Not Specified".

Comment: I would be using 2 queries. `UPDATE TableB SET TableB.Field3 = TableA.Value2 FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.Field3 = TableA.Code WHERE TableA.code NOT LIKE %CA% AND TableA.code NOT LIKE %IN%`, then `UPDATE TableB SET TableB.Field3 = TableA.Country FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.Field3 = TableA.Code WHERE TableA.code LIKE %CA% AND TableA.code LIKE %IN%`. This is not very pretty, but it might work.

Comment: @Cid thanks for the suggestion :), I do not want to hard code the codes as these might change once more data will be gathered, I want to keep it as dynamic as possible :)

Comment: you can use a IN clause then like : `WHERE TableA.code NOT IN ("CA", "IN")`, or, dynamically : `WHERE TableA.code NOT IN (SELECT ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with an `ISNULL`.

```
UPDATE TableB SET 
    Field3 = ISNULL(TableA.Country, 'NA')
FROM 
    TableB 
    LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableB.Field3 = TableA.Code
```

Using a `LEFT JOIN` won't force all `TableB` records to join against a `TableA` record, and the `ISNULL` will set a default value in case the `Code` doesn't exist on `TableA`.

Comment: I guess he wants only IN and CA. In his example, TableA.Country has a value for US and then can't be considered as NULL and will be replaced by an unwanted value (USA)

Comment: `US` won't match against any `Field3` so it won't update anything.